# Finding element in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have the follow code:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"e", @"è", @"é",@"i","ò",nil];

NSString *string = @"simpleè";
NSMutablestring *newString;

for(i=0>;i< [string length]; i++){
  if([stringa characterAtIndex:i] is in Array){
   [newString appendFormat:@"%c", [string characterAtIndex:i]];
 }
}
```

How make finding if single char of string stay in the array?
**Example of result:** 
newString= @"ieè";

Comment: Please provide more detail. I read your question 5 times but still do not know what you are talkin about

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to apply [rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:) repeatedly.  You'll have to create a [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCharacterSet) from the characters in your array somehow.

### Added

Though it probably would be just as simple to just loop through the string with `characterAtIndex` and compare each char (in an inner loop) to the chars in your array (which you could extract into a `unichar` array or put into a single `NSString` to make easier to access).

Answer (score 0):

Umm... if you want to check what the values are you can use NSLog

```
NSLog"%f", myFloat;
```

So you can use this to check your array... Which is what I think you are asking for, but the grammar in your question isn't very good. Please provide more details and better grammar.

Comment: I would find string's element that belong to array, then have a result into a new string. Sorry for the problem.

Comment: Wait do you mean, you want the code to check, if a string of text has a special character, you want to replace that special character with another character?

Comment: You couldn't do that anyway unless you are checking with a dictionary to see if that word exists and the meanings are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of your string and then match your string characters with the array and if found append that character in a new string.

```
 NSString *mstr = @"asdf";
  NSString *b = [ mstr characterAtIndex:0];
```

Hope it helps.......

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the characters in the string and then ask each string in the array for its `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`. If you find one where a range was actually found, then a character from the string is in the array. If not, then none of them are.

This might seem a bit roundabout, but Unicode makes looking at strings as just a series of "chars" rather unreliable, and you'll want to let your libraries do as much of the heavy lifting for you as they can.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this, but this is what I think you're trying to do:

```
NSMutableString* result= [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

for( int i= 0; i < [string length]; ++i ) {

    NSString* c= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [string characterAtIndex:i]];

    if( [myArray containsObject:c] )
        [result appendString:c];
}
```

Comment: Exactly! last question, for best method i must use NSCharacterSet for storage the characters into the array?

Comment: Since `characterAtIndex:` returns a unichar, I think you want `%C` in your format string rather than `%c`, which specifies an ordinary one-byte character.

Comment: Yes, I'm not an expert on Unicode and that sort of thing, but I think NSCharacterSet will be more robust than doing this manually.